# When automating CodedUI tests where would a 3rd party SDK that the test requires be installed?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

We have a coded UI test which requires a 3rd party SDK to operate. We use it to verify some objects created by the UI we are automating. So We have a build controller, a test controller, and a test agent. We think the build server with the build controller on it will build the tests. Now our question is will the tests be run from the build server? (so the 3rd party SDK needs to be installed there) or does it copy to the Test Machine where the test agent lives? (So the SDK needs to be installed on the machine where the tests execute)

So where do we need to install the SDK? Yes I know I can test it, but I don't want to leave a machine with an SDK uninstalled in case it leaves crud behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you? Yes you need to install the SDK in the machine that has the test agent and will run the test because the SDK like run-time files need to run the test as you said, but the build control not need to has SDK installed if your build didn't run test or reference any library in the SDK

Thanks

M.Radwan